# The difference in use and meaning for にくい, がたい and づらい

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I know they all mean something is 'difficult to do', 'hard to...' etc but why have three versions? are they used in different grammatical structures or contexts?

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29533/9831

Comment: Please [search for an answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search) before asking your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mean ...にくい。...づらい。...がたい。?like the following

I think these two are interchangeable. At least for me, I can’t find semantic difference.
“彼の説明は理解しにくい/理解しづらい” Both explains “it is hard for me to understand his explanation.

...がたい is a bit different. 
“彼の説明は理解しがたい。”

It is incomprehensible for me to understand his explanation. Or, it is  unlikely for me understand his explanation.

I think it is strange to use ...がたい for sense verb since they have the word describes hardness of physical property ...がたい.